# VsCode Python "run code" vs "run Python File in Terminal"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

This is probably a quite common problem. I use conda on osx. I set my conda env on the bottom left corner and of course installed all my dependencies.

If I run a python file in the terminal, everything works fine. If I run it on the output console, I get errors. That's because the output console, somehow does not use the same environment like my terminal.

Output Code main.py:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)

===

Users/[myself]/anaconda3/bin/python

===
```

Terminal main.py:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)

===

Users/[myself]/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python

===
```

My user settings:

```
{
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "workbench.settings.editor": "json",
    "workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings": true,
    "workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PATH": ""
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "todo-tree.tree.showScanModeButton": false,
    "python.showStartPage": false,
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "external",
    "prettier.printWidth": 100,
    "[jsonc]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "jupyter.alwaysTrustNotebooks": true,
    "cSpell.language": "en,de",
}
```

I did not configure any workspace settings. Is there a setting that I have missed?

Comment: You missed your code and the error message.

Comment: I added some code examples and my user settings

Comment: Could you do a `Cmd + Shift + P`, type `python: Select Interpreter` at the prompt and check that you are in the correct virtual environment?

Comment: I did, I am in the correct environment

Comment: @Julian -The reason is that no matter which terminal, when we use virtual environment or conda environment in VS Code, the terminal needs us to activate this environment, and "OUTPUT" does not automatically activate these environments by default, and "OUTPUT" as the output terminal cannot receive input. That is, the input command to activate the environment cannot be entered.